# Verifying the security of SAML SSO

Tags: penetration-test, identity, sso, saml, azure

I run an instance of a log aggregation product in the cloud, installed on a VM. I've strictly configured it's networking settings, internal firewall, internal port redirection, strong admin password, valid HTTPS certificate, etc. The web interface is publicly open to the web by design and I can't limit the access to it.

Since the product supports SAML SSO, I've also configured it to work with Azure AD as an identity provider for my organization, so I won't have to deal with managing additional passwords, 2FA and to avoid other security flaws.

What's the best way I can verify that the exposed web interface is as protected as it can be? Ideally I want to catch now as many problems and misconfigurations as I can, to minimize my risk of getting hacked for real.

Comment: IMO, this question needs improvement. It is effectively asking "how many different ways can I boil water?" I would recommend going back to the developer fo the product and asking "do you have any best practices in securing your product when it is configured for SAML SSO?" None of us here can answer as we know nothing other than you've protected your app with an identity provider connected to your Azure. It's far too general to assist.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewK. that this question is a little broad. The very high level answers are (1) peer review, (2) app scan, and (3) pen test. For a particular vendor, they may also have a lockdown or validation script that they can give you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that your log aggregation product and its dependencies are always up to date.
2. Ask the vendor whether they conduct regular penetration testing of their product, including the SAML setup.
3. If you are interested in performing a penetration test by yourself, you can use [[BurpSuite Community]](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload) with a [[SAML Raider extension]](https://epi052.gitlab.io/notes-to-self/blog/2019-03-13-how-to-test-saml-a-methodology-part-two/), which makes it possible to test SAML SSO for the most common misconfigurations.

In case you are interested in a more detailed SAML penetration testing checklist, you may find ours [here](https:////www.securing.pl/en/saml-what-can-go-wrong-security-check/).

4. Ensure that there is no leftover registration page in your application.
5. Verify if there are no excessive, publicly available services on other ports.

Without going into details, that's the best we can recommend, but there is still a possibility that your cloud configuration, your VM hardening, or your firewall is misconfigured, or that the product you use has some vulnerabilities. However, a person who knows more about the setup or can test it empirically will be able to propose a better-suited recommendation.

Comment: Make sure that you disclose your relationship to your links ...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have an internal Cybersecurity resource, you can hire a Managed Security Service Provider (MSSP) or you can use [free resources provided by the Cybersecurity & Infrastructure Security Agency (CISA)](https://us-cert.cisa.gov/resources/ncats) which will help report on potential vulnerabilities.